# ParseUser Log In error

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

So in the following code, I 100% of the time encounter the problem of ending up with the else statement, even though my login params are correct for various test accounts I've created.

```
View.OnClickListener loginListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        String usernameVal_login = usernameEditText_login.getText().toString();
        String passwordVal_login = passwordEditText_login.getText().toString();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ParseUser.logInInBackground(usernameVal_login, passwordVal_login, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, FunFactsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "There was an unexpected error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Any idea why it's not logging me in when I enter the right params for my logins?

**EDIT:**

Returns error:

`09-09 03:14:43.691  18687-18687/com.example.khaube.funfacts W/System.err﹕ com.parse.ParseException: invalid login credentials`

**ANSWER**

Turns out it was a logical error. The variables weren't being set onClick because they're within the listener but not in the method itself...silly me. Thanks for the suggestions, guys and gals!!

Comment: Write `e.printStackTrace()` in your else condition and paste your stacktrace

Comment: 09-09 03:14:43.691  18687-18687/com.example.khaube.funfacts W/System.err﹕ com.parse.ParseException: invalid login credentials ... So the ParseException is the problem, but that's the correct syntax according to Parse.com's documentation.

Comment: Log the value of user name and password inside onClick(). Check is the correct value getting in variable or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this way? I suppose you read EditText too early. You read credentials at the moment when you create listener but not when you click on login button.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       String usernameVal_login = usernameEditText_login.getText().toString();
       String passwordVal_login = passwordEditText_login.getText().toString();

        ParseUser.logInInBackground(usernameVal_login, passwordVal_login, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (user != null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, FunFactsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "There was an unexpected error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }enter code here
```

Comment: I saw that just a bit before you answered :) it was one of those "Did I really miss that?" moments. Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: Next time use a debugger. Or you could just log credentials before calling Parse API and check it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the log, your credentials (Username/Password) might be wrong.

Comment: The credentials are correct. I've double checked in my Parse userbase.

Comment: Try hardcoding a valid username, password in `ParseUser.logInInBackground`

Comment: Answer has been added to the OP. A simple logic error is all!